Importing a template of another cartridge in a cartridge template
Is it possible to import a template of a different cartridge in a cartridge template?
i.e at cartridges/it_cart_1/cartridge/templates/default/common/htmlHead.isml
to import cartridges/it_cart_2/cartridge/templates/default/common/component.isml
using some variation of
<isinclude template="it_cart_2:common/component.isml" />

I couldn't make it work and couldn't find any relevant documentation. I tried different order of cartridges in the pipeline, don't think it had any effect.

I did manage to hack this by setting up a controller that returns a static js resource, but its not very pretty. If anyone wants more details, you can ping me and I'll post a description.
